# Most flexible function signature in golang

Tags: go

I have object initializer in my code, that initializes every field of my object explicitly. But in my case, most of the parameters have sensible defaults and I want to use them.

In Python I usually use combination of keyword arguments or defaults and my `__init__` method contains some validation logic so I can use zero configuration principle in object initialization. For example:

```
class Foo:
    """This class designed to show zero configuration
    principle in action"""
    def __init__(self, mandatory, optional=None, **kwargs):
        self.__field1 = mandatory
        self.__field2 = optional or make_default2()
        if 'bar' in kwargs:
            self.__field3 = kwargs['bar']
        else:
            self.__field3 = make_default3()


f = Foo('mondatory', bar=Bar())
```

There is no parameters with default values in Go nor keyword parameters or function overloads. Because of that - it is difficult to write flexible initialization code (I don't care much about performance in such code usually).
I want to find most idiomatic way to write such code in Go. Maybe some combination of runtime type reflection and maps will do the job, what do you think?

Comment: Idiomatic way to do something in programming language is not "opinion based"!

Comment: Rob Pike is not an opinion. Rob Pike is one of the creators of the language.

Comment: So what? I doesn't argue about the language, I just ask about idioms that is common in this language and by the way, this idioms is not set in stone by creators by the language. How this can be opinion based?

Comment: Because Rob Pike's opinion about what is idiomatic in the language is what is idiomatic in the language.

Comment: And I'm trying to figure out what is idiomatic in the language asking about it, not arguing. What's wrong with it?

Comment: And Inmix told you what is idiomatic. Why are you so adamant that someone is arguing about this? The opinion of Rob Pike *is the idiom*.

Comment: This looks like misunderstanding. I write my first comment here after I get first close votes, seven hours before Inmix write his or her comment. I think that I get pretty good answers, actually I really use something that I have foound in this links. Everything is fine now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because newly-allocated memory in Go is always zeroed, the idiomatic way is to make explicit use of this fact by:

- designing your structs to have have sane zero values
- using composite literals

Take a look at the following section of Effective Go:
http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#data

For extremely complex cases, a configuration struct (option 3 at http://joneisen.tumblr.com/post/53695478114/golang-and-default-values) is also sometimes used, with a `NewConfigStruct()` that initializes a configuration instance with defaults. The user generates a default instance, sets the fields they want, then passes it to the `New` function for the actual struct they are creating.

Comment: Another option, from Rob Pike: http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2014/01/self-referential-functions-and-design.html