# what does make and new actually do?

Tags: go

In Go, if I want to create an Object of T, I can try these ways:

`t := T{}`  // t is the actual object created in the current stack
`p := &T{}`  // p is a pointer points to the actual object which is created in the current stack
`p := make(T)`  // p is a pointer points to the actual object which is created in the heap
`p := new(T)`  // p is a pointer points to the actual object which is created in the heap

I'm wondering whether my comments are correct or not?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25358332/6309

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between new and make?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358130/what-is-the-difference-between-new-and-make)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've written about this on my blog.

http://dave.cheney.net/2014/08/17/go-has-both-make-and-new-functions-what-gives

Answer (score 3):

> `t := T{} // t is the actual object created in the current stack`
>
> `p := &T{} // p is a pointer points to the actual object which is created in the current stack`
>
> `p := make(T) // p is a pointer points to the actual object which is created in the heap`
>
> `p := new(T) // p is a pointer points to the actual object which is created in the heap`
>
> I'm wondering whether my comments are correct or not?

Not quite, whether an object is allocated on the stack or the heap [depends on escape analysis](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/hSu4iZb38Fs) not the particular notation used to instantiate the object and actually [Dave wrote something about that](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/07/five-things-that-make-go-fast) also.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the type of the result is instructive.

- `make(T, ...)` returns type `T`. `make` can only be used for a few built-in types (slice, map, channel). It is basically a "constructor" for those types.
- `new(T)` returns type `*T`. It works for all types and does the same thing for all types -- it returns a pointer to a new instance of type `T` with zero value.